# How can I get PDFTextStripper to extract text row by row?

Tags: java, pdfbox

Here is an excerpt of the input (PDF):

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    public static String pdfPageToText(
        PDDocument docIn,
        int pageNumber
    ) {
        String pageText = "";
        try {
            PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper( );
            stripper.setStartPage( pageNumber );
            stripper.setEndPage( pageNumber );
            pageText = stripper.getText( docIn );
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            LOGGER.severe( e.getMessage( ) );
        }
        return pageText;
    }
```

The extracted text looks like this:

[image]

I would expect it to be more like this:

[image]

Please point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: try stripper.setSortByPosition(true), see https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#text-extraction

Comment: Beware, though, if the words you *perceive* to be at the same height actually are *not exactly* at the same height, `stripper.setSortByPosition(true)` may recognize them incorrectly as forming separate rows.